# Can we write $\int f(x)g(x)dx \leq C\int g(x)dx$ given that $\sup_x|f(x)|\leq C<+\infty$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Can we write $\int f(x)g(x)dx \leq C\int g(x)dx$ given that $\sup_x|f(x)|\leq C<+\infty$?
My answer is yes, but I'm confused with the following $\int f(x)dx \leq C\int dx$. What $\int dx$ means, is it just a length of integration, i.e. $\int_a^bdx = b -a$?

Comment: Yes, $\int \, dx$ just means $\int 1 \, dx$. Your inequality is trie **as long as** $g \geq 0$. For a counterexample in the general case, consider $f \equiv 0$ and $g \equiv -1$.

Comment: ... and $a \le b$.

Comment: This is only true for all the given $f$ if $g(x)\ge0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression $\int f(x)g(x)dx$ is in general a function (or strictly speaking, a set of functions). It is not a real number and thus it does not make sense to say that $\int f(x)g(x)dx\leq C\int g(x)dx$ as two sets of functions are generally non-comparable. You may consider rewriting your question using definite integrals.

Comment: You make a very good point.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct on both counts.

For your first question, you are using the fact that $p(x) \leq q(x) \Rightarrow \int_a^bp(x)dx \leq \int_a^bq(x)dx$. [As commented by PhoemueX, we need $g(x) \geq 0$, otherwise we cannot conclude $f(x)g(x) \leq Cg(x)$ from $f(x) \leq C$]

Your second question is just an application of the first where $g(x) = 1$.

Comment: I would mention something about $g(x)\ge0$, otherwise...